# Google Fit - Lost Connection to Data

Tags: android, flutter, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

Recently, we somehow lost connection to Google Fit data, and it seems only uninstalling and reinstalling the app will help us to gain connection, again. Even updating the app doesn't solve the issue.

For background: we do check permissions and we also tried to force grant permissions, but the OAuth screen wouldn't come up for us UNTIL we uninstalled and reinstalled the app.

We also recently had to resubmit our app for verification to use Google Fit.

Comment: Seems unusual. Were you able to capture the affected device model? Any patterns you noticed will also be helpful.

Comment: somehow it got resolved, not sure why.